# Collision do not work with smoke

Tags: smoke-simulation, collision

I have trouble with the collision when I’m doing a smoke simulation. It works fine if I open up a new Blender file but it doesn't work in my file that I'm working on and I can’t understand why. I want the smoke to be in the copper pipe and then make the pipe a little bit transparent (I know how to make it transparent). But the smoke isn't in the (marked) pipe since collision doesn't work. Is there someone that could understand why?

I have set the pipe to collision and the smoke to the domain.

Here is my **Blender file**: [image]

Here is the pipe I want to have the smoke in:
[image]

This is how I did it before that worked and how it should look like (a printscreen of a video):
[image]

Comment: Please do not use external links (especially not links that require to ask for authorization), upload the file to https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit the file into your quetion. If the file size is to large create a basic file which only holds the objects required for the smoke simulation like domain, emitter, effector(s) because they are the only relevant ones to investigate this issue. At first glance I see that the resolution divisions of the domain (the small cube in the corner) looks like they are much too large to fit into the tube without problems.

Comment: I have updated the Blender file. I think the size would not matter. And the smoke will follow the curve in the pipe. I belive that it is something else.

Comment: Well, the size does matter in many cases, I do not know yet without inspecting if this is the case here, but if voxels hardly fit inside where they should or are generated at the border lying half outside of the tube because of their size, this will matter. Trust my 10+ years doing smoke simulations. But as I said, this might not be the case here, I have to look at it when I have time - I just said it could be a reason since we had not the slightest information about your simulation setup.

Comment: Ok, but how is it then possible to do the smoke in the curve? I also tried to shrink it down but it did not work either.

Comment: The other question is do you really need the smoke to be simulated? I think in this case it would be much easier to just create an object and affect it with for example geometry nodes to make it seem like the smoke travels through the pipe.

Comment: @David I'm sorry I do not have time to try over and over again simulations with new settings, but I got it to work. First of all I noticed no object has its scale applied which can cause problems, so I applied the scale. Then everything is very small (okay, this might be real-life dimensions but this can cause problems as well), but I tried it anyway. I reduced the smoke velocity (0 for source and normal) from +5 to -2 on Y (because -Y is the direction inside the tube) and increased the sampling substeps because with these velocities a voxel can be outside the tube from one frame to the next.

Comment: But it did not work. I set the Timesteps Minimum to 2 and increased the resolution divisions to 500 and still the smoke got out of the tube although baking already takes really long now... and finally (and you might not like it because you said it has nothing to do with the voxel size) but after increasing the resolution divisions to 1000, the smoke stayed inside the tube. @Phönix64 I think so, too. Simulating this is overkill.

Comment: I appreciate that you tried. I will try the settings you did and see if I managed to get it to work @Gordon Brinksmann.

Comment: Since I did smoke before I really want to try to make it work so it fits in with the other things I have done in the video @Phönix64